# How do I get the legend tick marks to be properly positioned using heatmap.2 in R?

Tags: r, alignment, legend, heatmap

I am relatively new to R and am trying to use heatmap.2(). I have found it to be a great tool, except there is one detail that is driving me crazy. The tick marks in the legend do not line up perfectly with the colors I assign in the breaks.

Below is a minimal working example. In the legend the green area goes significantly over 1, however the bottom left portion of the heatmap (value = 1.0001) is blue as I specified in the breaks. I am using RStudio Version 0.99.486 if that makes a difference. Please help!

```
library(gplots)

M <- matrix(c(0.5,1.0001,2.1,3.9),nrow=2)

my_palette <- c('green','blue','purple','orange')
heatmap.2(M,Colv=NULL,Rowv=FALSE,dendrogram=NULL,trace='none',density.info='none',
          breaks=c(0,1,2,3,4),
          col=my_palette,
          key.xlab='',key.title='')
```

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613866/heatmap-2-and-color-key-tick-marks

Comment: I was able to replicate your problem... on my screen it looks like the tick marks are equally spaced and the green color block is too big.  I don't know this package well enough to help.  If nobody else helps you, you can try filing an issue on https://github.com/cran/gplots

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, in my case the plot renders as expected, it would be helpful to see your plot